# How to create 'component' from DeviceAdminReceiver in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am venturing into Android Development and am trying to follow the Android [tutorial on device admin](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html#kotlin).

I've a **DeviceAdminSample** class with the following content:

```kotlin
class DeviceAdminSample : DeviceAdminReceiver() {

    private fun showToast(context: Context, msg: String) {
        context.getString(R.string.admin_receiver_status, msg).let { status ->
            Toast.makeText(context, status, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }

    override fun onEnabled(context: Context, intent: Intent) =
        showToast(context, "admin_receiver_status_enabled")

    override fun onDisableRequested(context: Context, intent: Intent): CharSequence =
        context.getString(R.string.admin_receiver_status_disable_warning)

    override fun onDisabled(context: Context, intent: Intent) =
        showToast(context, context.getString(R.string.admin_receiver_status_disabled))

}
```

The tutorial is nice enough to give me this line:

> `private fun isActiveAdmin(): Boolean = dpm.isAdminActive(deviceAdminSample)`

And it also adds:

> Notice that the `DevicePolicyManager` method `isAdminActive()` takes a `DeviceAdminReceiver` component as its argument

I am clueless as to how to make that `DeviceAdminReceiver` **component** (presumably from `DeviceAdminSample` class).

A Java version of the code is:

```java
deviceAdminSample = new ComponentName(this, DeviceAdminSample.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as:

```
ComponentName(this, DeviceAdminSample::class.java)
```

What you could always do is copy paste the code from the tutorial and hope Android Studio recognize it as Java and ask you to translate it to Kotlin. If this does not occur, create a new Java file,  paste `new ComponentName(this, DeviceAdminSample.class);` and select `Code` > `Convert Java to Kotlin` at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

In Java you refer to a class like this: `DeviceAdminSample.class`, whereas in Kotlin you need `DeviceAdminSample::class.java`.

I would just upvote [Michiel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6932415/michiel)'s response or add a comment, but I don't have the reputation to do that yet.

Also, I put together a full example in Kotlin in a [Medium article here](https://medium.com/@codybrookshear/creating-an-android-device-owner-app-in-2023-b7e7b9fb3aca).